# Return all documents that a user has permission to at Search page load

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

If a user navigates to the Search page, it should immediately display all the documents that the user has permission to.

Is this achievable using Result Sources, if yes how?

How can I configure this?

Comment: What's the point? I mean, you can, easily, but why? There would be no relevance.

Comment: Its one of the requirement and it will be the homepage, so users can immediately see the documents that they have access to. the site's primarily function is search. well, currently, I am using result sources to return all items and documents. and I want to know if this is the ONLY solution :) thanks!

Comment: Just seem like a strange requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a result source that uses `*` as the query. Or, if you don't want to create the result source, drop a Search Results Web part on the page and change the query text to `*` (removing the default search parameter). You may want to add Sorting like by modified date and maybe add some additional refinement like only Documents. But that would depend on the business requirements.

If you only want documents you can use `IsDocument=1`. If you want OneDrive documents you can use `IsMyDocument=1`.

Comment: Wont this include list items, pages, and other things found in the site?

Comment: Yes, but I was not clear on what you wanted returned. If you just want documents then I have altered the answer.